# Java Swing - Resize JPanel on componentResized() event

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying to resize a JPanel to 100% width within a JFrame when window is resized. But the JPanel never gets resized...

I'm using IntelliJ

Here is my code:

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("MyApplication");
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
    contentPanel = new ContentPanel();

    MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    vimInitialiser = new VimInitialiser();

    frame.addWindowListener(mainFrame);
    frame.addComponentListener(mainFrame);

    JComponent newContentPane = mainFrame;
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 500));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    frame.add(menuPanel.getMenuPanel());
    frame.add(contentPanel.getContentPanel());
}
```

Here is my JPanel classes:

```
    public class ContentPanel extends JPanel{

    public JPanel getContentPanel(){
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("ContentPanel");
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(940, 480));
        contentPanel.setBorder(border);

        contentPanel.add(label);

        return contentPanel;
    }
}

    public class MenuPanel extends JPanel{

    public JPanel getMenuPanel(){
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("MenuPanel");
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 480));
        menuPanel.setBorder(border);
        menuPanel.add(label);

        return menuPanel;
    }
}
```

Pleas help me whit this problem.

Comment: You might need to use a different layout manager. If my memory is correct `GridbagLayout` wouldn't necessarily resize a component beyond its preferred size. You could try `BorderLayout` etc. or use a 3rd party layout manager (MiG layout is one of the best IMO).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `BorderLayout`.

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

And then add the panes like this:

```
frame.add(menuPanel.getMenuPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH); 
frame.add(contentPanel.getContentPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: pack(); and setVisible(true); should be last code lines in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mistake is that you are not setting the 'fill' and 'weight' for the gridbagconstraints.  I think this will solve the problem.

```
GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
frame.add(menuPanel, gridBagConstraints);
frame.add(contentPanel, gridBagConstraints);
```

You might need to play around a little with the constraints to get it to line up exactly how you want.